# Tinymce works fine in my app but not in admin - Django

Tags: django, django-admin, tinymce

I have a form in my app that has `content` attribute and uses tinymce like so:

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class SomeModel(models.Model):
   content = HTMLField('Content', null=True)
```

I also set up my tinymce in the installed apps and have the registered its url.

In my app it works fine and the user can edit and enter his\her content using tinymce. but when I register this model to the admin, all fields appear fine except the content which does not appear to have any way to input (and because its a required field, this means that I cant enter new items through the admin).

this looks like this in the admin:
[image]

how can I make tinymce also available in the admin screen?

bonus question: is there a safe way to use tinymce while letting the users use tinymce (currently im using `form | safe` which im guessing isn't really safe.

Answer (score 0):

Create ModelForm

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
```

**Admin.py**

```
from models import Blog
from forms import BlogForm

class BlogAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogForm()
```

Comment: I already had a form. and all the rest of the fields from that form appear except the tinymce one. I tried making an admin class like you showed and set the form attribute to my form. did not help

Comment: see there is no any other configuration look at your code there is must be smaller mistake

Comment: thats not very helpful